# Getting .apply is not a function

Tags: json, angular, typescript

does anyone know why I'm getting:

**ERROR** **TypeError: _this.user_data.apply is not a function**

While tying to populate user_data with a mapped result from a JSON file

```
user_data: any;

this.testService.getTestWithObservable()
 .map( result => result.map( i => i.users.data) )
 .subscribe(
    res => {

        this.user_data = [];
        res.forEach(i => this.user_data(...i));
        console.log(this.user_data);
    }
);
}
```

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "users": {
        "user_id": 14,
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Damien",
            "age": 25
        }]
    }
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "users": {
        "user_id": 11,
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Damien",
            "age": 25
        }]
    }
}]
```

I can't find anything related to this error/code

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `res.forEach(i => this.user_data(...i));`? Because it tries to call `this.user_data` as a function by using the brackets but you just assigned an array to this.user_data: `this.user_data = [];` one line before.

Comment: Just edited the OP with the JSON. What I'm trying to do is print name and age of both users with ngFor but if instead I use this code in the subscribe function (this.user_data = res;) it won't print anything. The only workaround I've found was to pass the index by myself (this.user_data = res[0];) but It only shows user 1 name and age

Comment: Shouldn't this work by using `res.forEach(i => this.user_data[] = i);`?

Comment: If I do that, the latest value of "i" seems to overwrite the previous one so it always shows the very last index. Anyways I just got it working, thanks for contributing. The solution was on adding an extra iteration of ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

**TS**

```
       res => {
           this.user_data= res;
       }
```

**HTML**

```
   <div *ngFor="let data of user_data">
       <div *ngFor="let x of data">
        {{ x.name}}
       </div>
   </div>
```